# How to replace specific value for one variable?

Tags: r

I am trying to use "29.05" to replace a outlier (29.95)in variable of Enterdateofexam2, so I tried this code in R studio:

```
jimma3n<-jimma3 %>%
       select(Enterdateofexam2, Enterdayofexam, UniqueKey,MEDICALRECORD)%>%
       mutate(
            day=str_sub(Enterdateofexam2, 1,2),
            month=str_sub(Enterdateofexam2, 4,5)
              )%>%
      filter(as.numeric(day)>30 | as.numeric(month)>13) %>% #By Ethiopian calendar, each month has 30 days and total thirteen months 
      str_replace(Enterdateofexam2,"29.25","29.05")
```

Then I got wrong message from R, saying:

Error in str_replace(., Enterdateofexam2, "29.25", "29.05") :
unused argument ("29.05"),

Similarly, I also cannot use str_split and separate function to achieve "mutate" I am using now. Say I want to split character of "29.95" in to "29" and "95" if I use:

```
 "str_split(Enterdateofexam, ".", 2)
```

or

```
separate(Enterdateofexam2,c("col1", "col2"), ".")
```

in this environment, they all don't work. I don't know whether it is because of the format of my "Enterdateofexam2", maybe it is not valid vector? Can anyone help to figure out how to fix it? Thanks~~!

Answer (score 2):

We need `str_replace` in `mutate`

```
jimma3 %>%
       select(Enterdateofexam2, Enterdayofexam, UniqueKey,MEDICALRECORD)%>%
       mutate(
            day=str_sub(Enterdateofexam2, 1,2),
            month=str_sub(Enterdateofexam2, 4,5)
              )%>%
      filter(as.numeric(day)>30 | as.numeric(month)>13) %>% #By Ethiopian calendar, each month has 30 days and total thirteen months 
      mutate(Enterdateofexam2 = str_replace(Enterdateofexam2,"29.25","29.05"))
```

Comment: Effectively the same thing, I would have used mutate(Enterdateofexam2 = replace(Enterdateofexam2, Enterdateofexam2 == "29.25","29.05")). I wonder if there is any benefit to using one over the other?